# What's the login for phpMyAdmin?

Tags: authentication, passwords, phpmyadmin, xampp

I downloaded the most recent version of XAMPP (v.1.7.7) and decided start a database. When I opened phpMyAdmin, it alerts me there is a new version of phpMyAdmin available. I downloaded it from online, and I deleted the old version of phpMyAdmin and replaced it with the current version (v.3.5.1). I opened it up and it came up with a log-in screen. I entered in "root" without a password, but it alerts me I need one. I don't know any password nor I know any alternative log-ins. How would I log-in to enter phpMyAdmin?

Comment: what about `root` as password or `password`

Comment: root, password, and admin dont work as the password

Comment: Can you find the file `/htdocs/xampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` ? Look for `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']` in this file if you can.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Enabling login without a password, to make it work exactly as before

You'll need to change your configuration file. Open up your XAMPP installation directory, browse to the folder `phpmyadmin`, and look for a file called `config.inc.php`. If there isn't one already, you'll first need to copy `config.sample.inc.php` to `config.inc.php`. Then, just open `config.inc.php` and find this line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

Change it to:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

#### Alternatively, just add a password

Open a command prompt and type this, followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p pass
```

When it asks you for the current password, just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again. Then set the new password, and log in to phpMyAdmin using that.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this method, but I havent thought of changing the file name. ;)

Comment: @zeldarulez: Just in case you want to add a password, too... see edit :)

Comment: mysqladmin -u root -p pass      Need explanation... after what circumstances does this work?

Answer (score 19):

Default is:

```
Username: root

Password: (just leave it blank)
```

The Password is set to 'password' in some versions.

Answer (score 0):

In new versions note that you have to change your code to like this:

```
mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_dbname);
```

And for more look to this:
[Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579099/fatal-error-uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect)