# Setting up phpMyAdmin username and password

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

When I go to localhost/phpmyadmin/ the first screen I get ask me for username and password.

I haven't create one. How can I create one? I assume there must be a file on my XAMPP I need to edit.

I couldn't find such a file.

I understand this might not be an appropriate question in here but I really need to set this up and I don't seem to find anything online.

Comment: Try with. user = root and with no password.

Answer (score 2):

Your username/password is the credentials you created on your mysql database. So for example, if you connect to mysql using the username 'foo' and the password 'bar', this is the credentials used to log into phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, when I first started using XAMPP, this was simply ursername:root and no password.  However, if this isn't the case, you might have to go through a couple more steps, which have already been outlined quite nicely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10866765/2825638) in another post.