# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a simple connection with XAMPP and MySQL server, but whenever I try to enter data or connect to the database, I get this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php:22
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 22

Example of line 22:

```
$link = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname , $mysql_username);
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: <?php

$mysql_hostname = "my ip";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "police";
$db = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname , $mysql_username) 
 or die("Connection problem With SQL. Hostname , Username Or Password are wrong!");

mysql_select_db($mysql_database,$db) or die("Could Not connect to databse! check credentials");

mysql_connect($mysql_hostname , $mysql_username) 

?>

Comment: Change mysql_connect($mysql_hostname , $mysql_username)  to mysql_connect($mysql_hostname , $mysql_username, $mysql_password) . Also, switch to PDO or MySQLi!

Comment: in case that I dont use a password on phpmyadim ? (trying to do all those remote things just cause I need the cellphone to be able to connect to the database)

Comment: If you come across this error with legacy _CodeIgniter_, use this in your `config/database.php`: `'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',` (change `mysql` to `mysqli`.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

`mysql_*` functions have been removed in PHP 7.

You probably have PHP 7 in XAMPP. You now have two alternatives: [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 44):

You can use `mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname , $mysql_username)` instead of `mysql_connect($mysql_hostname , $mysql_username)`.

`mysql_*` functions were removed as of PHP 7. You now have two alternatives: [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Other changes to your code are likely to be needed, though.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, this required the `php7.0-mysql` package. As @ceejayoz says, there are actually several API changes required, and not just to function names but to the order of their arguments. Very frustrating.

Comment: Rough one but it worked for me, at least till i optimise my code with PDO connection

Answer (score 26):

It is recommended to use either the MySQLi or PDO extensions. **It is not recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development, as it was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and was removed in PHP 7.**

PHP offers three different APIs to connect to MySQL. Below we show the APIs provided by the mysql, mysqli, and PDO extensions. Each code snippet creates a connection to a MySQL server running on "example.com" using the username "username" and the password "password". And a query is run to greet the user.

**Example #1 Comparing the three MySQL APIs**

```
<?php
// mysqli
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "username", "password", "database");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT 'Hello, dear MySQL user!' AS _message FROM DUAL");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo htmlentities($row['_message']);

// PDO
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=example.com;dbname=database', 'username', 'password');
$statement = $pdo->query("SELECT 'Hello, dear MySQL user!' AS _message FROM DUAL");
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo htmlentities($row['_message']);

// mysql
$c = mysql_connect("example.com", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 'Hello, dear MySQL user!' AS _message FROM DUAL");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo htmlentities($row['_message']);
?>
```

I suggest you try out both MySQLi and PDO and find out what API design you prefer.

Read [Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/5700401)

Answer (score 14):

`mysql_*` functions have been removed in PHP 7.

You now have two alternatives: [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

The following is a before (-) and after (+) comparison of a migration to the MySQLi alternative, taken straight out of working code:

```
-if (!$dbLink = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass))
+if (!$dbLink = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass))

-if (!mysql_select_db($dbName, $dbLink))
+if (!mysqli_select_db($dbLink, $dbName))

-if (!$result = mysql_query($query, $dbLink)) {
+if (!$result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $query)) {

-if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
+if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

-while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC )) {
+while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC )) {

-mysql_close($dbLink);
+mysqli_close($dbLink);
```

Answer (score 14):

As other answers suggest... Some guy (for whatever reason) decided that your old code should not work when you upgrade your PHP, because he knows better than you and don't care about what your code does or how simple it is for you to upgrade.

Well, if you can't upgrade your project overnight you can

> downgrade your version of PHP to whatever version that worked

or...

> use a shim (kind of polyfill) such as https://github.com/dshafik/php7-mysql-shim or https://github.com/dotpointer/mysql-shim, and then find a place for  `include_once("choice_shim.php");` somewhere in your code

That will keep your old PHP code up and running until you are in a mood to update...

Answer (score 4):

`mysql_` functions have been removed from PHP 7. You can now use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

MySQLi example:

```
mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_dbname);
```

[`mysqli_connect` reference link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have not committed a typo as in my case

> msyql_fetch_assoc should be *mysql*

Answer (score -2):

For mysqli you can use :

$db = ADONewConnection('mysqli');

...
...

$db->execute("set names 'utf8'");

Answer (score -2):

in case of a similar issue when I'm creating dockerfile I faced the same scenario:-
I used below changed in mysql_connect function as:-

if($CONN = @mysqli_connect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASS)){
//mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'gbk'", $CONN);