# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysql

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string()  in
>   /var/www/engine/database.php on line 38

I can still connect to the database however. Why is it not available?

I am using PHP version 7.1.4

Comment: mysql_* removed in PHP 7

Comment: which mysql connectivity are you using. are you using `mysqli` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql\_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579099/fatal-error-uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect)

Comment: @BhuneshSatpada I didnt get ur question about mysql connectivity. Could u give some clarity on your question

Comment: @B.Desai What is the alternative?

Comment: use mysqli_* instead

Comment: And why is PDO tagged?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile, Sorry It was added bymistakely

Answer (score 7):

`mysql_` has been  removed in php 7. try `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Error : mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly two parameters. but we have only one parameter. mysqli_real_escape_string($username)

Comment: you need to provide first parameter is your connection variable and  other one is posted parameter. so your syntax will will `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name'])`

[link] (https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp)

Comment: can you post your database connectivity code?

Comment: Problem solved. Thank You

Comment: Great. It fixed my many problem

Answer (score 1):

The mysql extension has been deprecated from PHP 5.5. Use mysqli extension should be used.

You can try mysqli_real_escape_string() for your PHP Version.

Comment: Error : mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly two parameters. but we have only one parameter. mysqli_real_escape_string($username)

Comment: Syntax :-  mysqli_real_escape_string(connection,escapestring);

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);

Comment: What should I pass as the connection parameter

Comment: Problem solved Thankyou