# DVWA Create/Reset Database

Tags: php, mysql, apache

After setting up all the configuration correctly on Kali Linux for dvwa. While, selecting *create/reset database* . The screen is greeting me with a blank page.

Not able to figure out since few days.

Setup Check:

Operating System: *nix
Backend Database: Mysql
PHP version:7.0.26-1
Web Server Server_Name:127.0.0.1

PHP function display_errors : disabled
PHP function safe_mode: disabled
PHP function allow_url_include: enabled
PHP function allow_url_fopen: enabled
PHP function magic_quotes_gpc:disable
PHP module php-gd: installed

reCAPTCHA key : xxxxxxx

Writable folder /var/www/html/dvwa/hackable/uploads/: yes
Writable file/var/www/html/dvwa/external/phpids/0.6/lib/IDS/tnp/phpids_log.txt: yes

Comment: blank page is 500 error, check your error logs. and post your code.

Comment: Where do I check for error log file in kali linux?

Comment: `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: change into root, `sudo su` or just to view it `sudo tail /var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: https://github.com/ethicalhack3r/DVWA/issues/183

Comment: Wed Jan 03 01:29:13.677248 2018] [:error] [pid 2311] [client 127.0.0.1:43524] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/dvwa/dvwa/includes/DBMS/MySQL.php:9\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/dvwa/setup.php(17): include_once()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/dvwa/dvwa/includes/DBMS/MySQL.php on line 9, referer: http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/setup.php

Comment: Google `Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()` its common.

Comment: how do I overcome this issue? @LawrenceCherone

Comment: Tip, instead of installing on the host and polluting the system, you should do it in a [LXC container](https://linuxcontainers.org/), then you can install ubuntu 14.04 etc and remove it all after testing..

Comment: @LawrenceCherone can you please elaborate? As of now on my Virtual box i only have kali linux installed

Comment: If it on virtualbox you wont need LXD lol, i was presuming your actually using linux. Your need to install the deprecated extension `mysql_*` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579099/fatal-error-uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect

Answer (score 0):

All logs on kali_linux are now managed by "journalctl" this includes system logs, apache logs, kernel logs, etc...

Comment: make sure you also configured DVWA it according to your system