# Enabling mysql support in PHP

Tags: php, mysql-connector

I am trying to add MySql support in PHP. I am using PHP version 7.2.11. When i'm trying to run my application, it shows the following error:

```
Your PHP installation does not have MySQL support. Please enable MySQL support in PHP or ask your web host to do so for you.
```

This problem didn't occur when i tried with older versions of PHP. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable MySQLi extension in php 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424982/how-to-enable-mysqli-extension-in-php-7)

Comment: Is there any solution without converting to MySQLi

Comment: No, `MySQL` is deprecated on `PHPv5.5.0` up to now.  Some reasons why you would never `mysql` you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-when-using-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql\_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579099/fatal-error-uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect)

Comment: @imtiazrupu yes, there is another solution: convert to PDO :) The mysql extension has been removed from php 7. Period. You really should move away from that extension. If you insist on using it, then you need to downgrade your php version.

Answer (score 0):

1- Update the required packages
If your are running an Ubuntu VPS and PHP 7, then run the following commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

if you are running a CentOS VPS and you have PHP 7, then run the following commands to fix the problem:

```
yum update
yum install php70w-mysql
```

2- Restart the Web Server,

If your are running an Ubuntu, then run the following commands:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

If your are running an CentOS, then run the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl reload httpd.service
```