# How to log on to phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I downloaded WAMP and Wordpress. The localhost is working. But when i need to log on to phpmyAdmin it asks for a password .. how to create that password.

Please be simple in your answer. I am new here. Thank you all.

Comment: default password is blank and username is root i think

Comment: Enter your mysql username and password. Go through with the PMA documentation first.

Comment: Go through this artical https://hsnyc.co/how-to-set-the-mysql-root-password-in-localhost-using-wamp/

Comment: Possible duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866696/whats-the-login-for-phpmyadmin
though this one is for XAMPP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1 : You have not specified password still ask**

This is asking for your MySQL username and password. You should enter these details, which will default to `"root"`and`""` (i.e.: nothing) if you've not specified a password.

```
Username : root
password : blank
```

**Case 2 : Add password or change that will be here**

Can you set the password to the phpmyadmin here

```
http://localhost/security/index.php
```

**Change Password of PMA user**

there is config.inc.php file in the phpmyadmin folder.Change username and password to the one you have set for your database.

```
/* Authentication type and info */


$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'enter_username_here';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'enter_password_here';
```

Comment: IT WORKED .. ROOT and password is Black. Thank you Vasim.

Comment: can you tell how?